# What are all the restrictions on existential generalization (When CAN'T we use it)?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, fake-proofs

I know that I am using existential generalization wrong here, I don't know exactly how but the conclusion is absurd.

Let $F$ be any functional predicate.

1. $F(x)=F(x)$ **axiom**
2. $\forall x(F(x)=F(x))$ **universal generalization $x$/$x$ (1)**
3. $\exists y\forall x(F(x)=y)$ **existential generalization $y$/$F(x)$ (2)**
4. $\forall x(F(x)=z)$ **existential instantiation $z$/$y$ (3)**
5. $F(a)=z$ **universal instantiation $a$/$x$ (4)**
6. $F(b)=z$ **universal instantiation $b$/$x$ (4)**
7. $F(a)=F(b)$ **substitution $F(b)$/$z$ (5)(6)**
8. $\forall y(F(a)=F(y))$ **universal generalization $y$/$b$ (7)**
9. $\forall x,y(F(x)=F(y))$ **universal generalization $x$/$a$ (8)**

This would conclude esentially that every definable function only has one value for all its arguments, which is clearly false (but if you want me to make this post longer and show that then I can).

I've always thought (and have seen in a couple places online) that Universal Instantiation and existential generalization have no restrictions. I thought that the following was a tautology:

$Px\implies\exists xPx$

Can someone educate me on when we **CAN'T** use existential generalization?

Comment: Your step from 2 to 3 isn't a valid instance of existential introduction (which you call existential generalisation). (it is certainly not an instance of $P(x) \rightarrow \exists z P(x)$.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What set of formal rules can we use to safely apply Universal/Existential Generalizations and Specifications?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848340/what-set-of-formal-rules-can-we-use-to-safely-apply-universal-existential-genera)

Comment: @TankutBeygu This post is  extremely helpful but I couldn't find anything about instantiating values of functional predicates that would help me understand what is wrong with my "proof"

Comment: Line 2 is invalid. You could say $\exists x (F(x)=F(x))$

Comment: Step 2 to 3 is simply wrong because you are acting on a bound variable; from 2) what you can do is the useless $∃y∀x(F(x)=F(x))$. Alternatively, from 2) $(y=y)$ by UI and then $\exists y (y=y)$.

Comment: Having said that, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188860/give-a-deduction-of-existential-generalization-varphi-tx-rightarrow-exists): the inference Px⟹∃xPx is fine.

Comment: Regarding restrictions of quantifiers rules, see the post [The problem of Free Variables in natural deduction rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313341/the-problem-of-free-variables-in-natural-deduction-rules-forall-exists). Universal Elimination as well as Existential Introduction have **no** restrictions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Not with regard to free and bound variables, but you do have to replace *all* occurrences of the term with the new existentially quantified variable. Failure to do this is the fallacy here.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss - no. The EI rule is $\varphi [t/x] \to \exists x \varphi$ that mrsns that $(x=0)[0/x] \to \exists x(x=0)$ is correct.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the main problem here is that I quantified over a bound variable? Is $F(x)$ bound or just the $x$?

Comment: Yes, the error is that you cannot apply Existential Gen (step 3) to the variable $x$ that is not free. Thus, the correct derivation is: 1) ok, 2) $\exists y (F(x)=y)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is pedagogically always better to learn Fitch-style natural deduction systems such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820). The reason that logic texts often introduce Hilbert-style systems is that they are a bit easier to reason **about**. But they are **totally impractical** for actual mathematics, and certainly bad for new students learning FOL.

In particular, take a look at the ∃intro rule in the linked system. It says that **if** you have deduced "E ∈ S" for some object expression "E" in the **current context**, and have deduced "Q(E)", **then** you can deduce "∃x∈S ( Q(E) )" in the **same context**. So it cannot be used in the way you tried in your question, because in my Fitch-style system you cannot have any undeclared variable and so the proof has to look like:

```
Given x∈obj:
  F(x) = F(x).  [1]
∀x∈obj ( F(x) = F(x) ).  [2]
// Everything below this is WRONG //
F(x)∈obj.  [3]
∃y∈obj ∀x∈obj ( F(x) = y ).  [4]
```

- Unlike in most Hilbert-style systems, [1] **cannot** be deduced outside its subcontext, because "x" must be declared before "F(x)" is meaningful.
- [2] is deduced in the global context, but observe that "x" in the global context is **not referring to anything**; it was only referring inside the subcontext.
- The variable "x" in [2] is only meaningful under the ∀-quantification, and **not** outside it. This a "x" is sometimes called a dummy variable since it merely conveys what the quantification is. As you ought to expect, [2] is equivalent to ∀y∈obj ( F(y) = F(y) ), in which "y" is the dummy variable.
- [3] is wrong precisely because "x" is not meaningful there, nor is "F(x)".

Here is a more striking example of your logical fallacy:

```
Given x∈obj:
  x = x.
∀x∈obj ( x = x ).
// Everything below this is WRONG //
x∈obj.
∃y∈obj ∀x∈obj ( x = y ).
```

So the fallacy has nothing to do with function-symbols! I will note that my deductive system for FOL permits the universe `obj` to be empty, unlike the other common kind of deductive system. Both kinds of systems are equally powerful, but the kind that my system belongs to is the more intuitive kind, so once you understand the key ideas it will be obvious what the inference rules should be. These two kinds differ in that the other kind proves ∃x ( x = x ) whereas my system does **not** prove ∃x∈obj ( x = x ). I hope the above explanation of your fallacy lets you see how this is related.

In any case, feel free to ask further in comments!